# Return type of PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, function, return-type, greenplum

A postgreSQL function where we don't actually knows the returning columns and their datatype as only the input values are going to decide which result set will be returned.
How to handle such case?

Tried creating return type as record but that also ask you to mention the column names of result set.

Comment: You can return json.

Comment: It doesn't sound a very good use case for a function.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to create a function for greenplum database where the result set and their datatype depends on the input values. There can be different dataset having different set of columns for the output.